# Can the Mikheyev-Smirnov-Wolfenstein (MSW) effect be modified by non-standard neutrino-neutrino interactions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, neutrinos, interactions, beyond-the-standard-model

The [MSW effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikheyev%E2%80%93Smirnov%E2%80%93Wolfenstein_effect) describes how propagation of neutrinos through matter can resonantly enhance the neutrino mixing. The reason for this enhancement is that the presence of electrons in matter changes the energy levels of the neutrino propagation eigenstates, due to charged-current coherent forward scattering of the electron neutrinos (via [weak interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction)). This effect is especially important for the propagation of [solar neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino).

Non-standard (i.e., beyond the Standard Model) neutrino interactions with electrons can modify the MSW effect (see e.g. p. 7 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/0034-4885/76/4/044201)).

Now my question is: is it also possible that non-standard neutrino-neutrino interactions (such as the ones mediated by [Majorons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majoron)) modify the MSW effect?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed non-stardard interactions can modify neutrino mixing. Here's one paper that discusses a few types of NSI and their effect on the solar survival probability.

- R. Bonventre, A. LaTorre, J.R. Klein, G.D. Orebi Gann, S. Seibert, and O. Wasalski, "Nonstandard models, solar neutrinos, and large $θ_{13}$", [*Phys. Rev. D* **88**, 053010](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.88.053010), [arXiv:1305.5835](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.5835).

I'm not personally aware of any paper that discusses the affect of Majorons in particular on neutrino mixing though.